# Android studio on new project start with c++ support gives mulitple errors?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-ndk

When i start a new project with c++ support , the newly created project fails to recognize native Jni function in main activity.
on opening my native-lib.cpp
these errors are appearing as shown in image

[image: Jni-lib.cpp]

on running the project these errors i get

```
 Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build D:\2019 android\OPENCV3\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\x86 --target native-lib}
Unknown argument android\OPENCV3\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\x86
Usage: cmake --build <dir> [options] [-- [native-options]]
Options:
  <dir>          = Project binary directory to be built.
  --target <tgt> = Build <tgt> instead of default targets.
                   May only be specified once.
  --config <cfg> = For multi-configuration tools, choose <cfg>.
  --clean-first  = Build target 'clean' first, then build.
                   (To clean only, use --target 'clean'.)
  --use-stderr   = Ignored.  Behavior is default in CMake >= 3.0.
  --             = Pass remaining options to the native tool.
```

Comment: _"Unknown argument android\OPENCV3\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\x86"_  Don't use paths with spaces in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rename `D:\2019 android` to `D:\2019_android`, and all your troubles will cure.